# DataGridView Checkbox Column cannot display correctly in one workstation when customized it

Tags: c#, datagridview

I got a problem that when I created a customize control using panel and added a DataGridView into it, one of workstation cannot show the checkbox column checkbox (just show a empty column which haven't see the checkbox) and that DataGridView ordering is totally changed.

I have tested to uninstall and re-install all the .net framework (include uninstalled 1.1), and tried to copy the System.Windows.Forms.dll to that workstation (.net 2.0 folder) but the problem is still here.  Any idea of this case?  Any method of panel or datagridview I can call?

P.S.  99% of workstations are work in normal, but I need to fix the only one workstation which contain this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Check if the font settings on that machine are different in regards to size. It might influence rendering.

Comment: Hi Mikael, Thanks your response, I don't sure the font size is different or not but I remember that workstation has adjusted some of thing (e.g. exit, max-button) is larger, if this case, how to make the checkbox column normal without changing the user default settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the system's DPI setting.  On XP its under Display Properties > Settings tab > Advanced button.  On the top of the General tab in the Advanced dialog, you'll see the DPI setting.  96 is default.  This might be what Mikael was meaning, but I'm not sure.